# mysqldump, preserve update_time and modify_time attributes as listed by show table status from

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, information-schema

Does `mysqldump` preserve the `create_time` and `update_time` attributes that are output by `show table status from`?

If not, is there an option that does this?

[From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml) it looks like mysqldump preserves this data if you export to XML.
EDIT: Well the data is included in the export. Whether it's read in at the other end I'm not sure.

Is there a way to do this with a normal `.sql` dump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to reload the INFORMATION_SCHEMA manually. All the tables are dynamica entities. For instance, look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`:

```
mysql> show create table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: TABLES
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `TABLES` (
  `TABLE_CATALOG` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_TYPE` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ENGINE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VERSION` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROW_FORMAT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE_ROWS` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAX_DATA_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `INDEX_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA_FREE` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTO_INCREMENT` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPDATE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHECK_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE_COLLATION` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHECKSUM` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATE_OPTIONS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE_COMMENT` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

It is a temporary table. If you restart mysql, how does it get populated? Evidently, it is popoulated during mysql startup. What would be included? Retrieve OS metadata of the table.

Let's look at mysql.user from the OS

```
[root@*** ~]# ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.*
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 10466 Jun  5  2012 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  2144 Jul 15 23:29 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  2048 Dec 10 18:25 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYI
```

Let's look at mysql.user from the mysql client:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.tables
    -> where table_schema='mysql' and table_name='user'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
   TABLE_SCHEMA: mysql
     TABLE_NAME: user
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: MyISAM
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Dynamic
     TABLE_ROWS: 31
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 69
    DATA_LENGTH: 2144
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 281474976710655
   INDEX_LENGTH: 2048
      DATA_FREE: 0
 AUTO_INCREMENT: NULL
    CREATE_TIME: 2012-06-05 23:45:23
    UPDATE_TIME: 2012-07-15 23:29:05
     CHECK_TIME: NULL
TABLE_COLLATION: utf8_bin
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS:
  TABLE_COMMENT: Users and global privileges
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Please notice the following

- The Creation Time

  - file datetime for `.frm` is `Jun  5  2012`
  - `CREATE_TIME: 2012-06-05 23:45:23`
- The Update Time

  - file datetime for `.MYD` is `Jul 15 23:29`
  - `UPDATE_TIME: 2012-07-15 23:29:05`

The OS metadata for `mysql.user` is loaded into `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` on mysql startup and is updated through INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs.

## SUMMARY

While you can mysqldump `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, it is impossible to manually reload it. Theoretically, you could shutdown mysql, tweek the OS clock, tweek every file, then startup mysql. It's not worth the effort.

Comment: Awesome response and that makes perfect sense. So I suppose if I was really bothered about the update_time and create_time is reload the data, shut down the server, modify the file date times, start the server. I was curious as to whether there was an option to include this in one of the mysqldump comment blocks. It's not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer, there is no way to preserve the time info in files created by mysqldump.

But I think the following idea may still be useful because it actually helps to preserve the `information_schema.tables` in a different way.

The solution I adopted was creating a table which contains the info, by running these two queries. The 1st one is only to create the table and fill in the 1st time info. Run the 2nd one each time you wish to append new info in the future:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myserver_tables SELECT my_current_tables.* 
FROM (
 SELECT NOW() AS time_stamp,tables.* FROM information_schema.tables
) AS my_current_tables;

INSERT INTO myserver_tables SELECT my_current_tables.* 
FROM (
 SELECT NOW() AS time_stamp,tables.* FROM information_schema.tables
) AS my_current_tables;
```

Executing the 2nd query periodically, I keep the information about all my tables and their evolution in time.