# Preserving create_time when loading a mysqldump file

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I want to make a copy of a MySQL database but preserve the information_schema.create_time for each of the tables. I haven't been able to find an option to do that with mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

There's a response for this here: [MySQL - mysqldump. preserve update_time and modify_time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31542/mysqldump-preserve-update-time-and-modify-time-attributes-as-listed-by-show-tab)

As @RolandoMySQLDBA said:

> There is no way to reload the INFORMATION_SCHEMA manually. All the tables are dynamic entities.