# How to test mysql for changes

Tags: mysql, change-management

I'm OCD person, I think I accidentally dropped something in my mysql.

Problem is I've around 50 databases, and I cannot manually check everything :(

Is there a way to check for these kind of changes? I tried to look at timestamps in /var/lib/mysql but it didn't help, I was looking at directory timestamps.

I also ran:

`SELECT table_schema,table_name,update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE update_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day)`

it only returned databases changed in last few secs.

Comment: But if you dropped a table, it wouldn't be in the information_schema anymore. Or was it an INDEX, COLUMN, FK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much floundering around with the information_schema.tables table, I finally discovered the answer to your problem - update time doesn't work for InnoDB. See the points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated) by a.out and ajacian81.

The only way you can do this is to implement [logging tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369829/470530) (as suggested by Bill Karwin, a bit of a MySQL/database guru).

The only other thing that I can think of is to use a backup and use a diff programme to compare the text output of queries from your current and backup database. Horrible I know, but there are tools which can do this if it's critical. There's MySQL's own (MySQLdiff - in utilities), you could try [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyaway](http://flywaydb.org/) (which I believe have this functionality) or Google "[database diff programmes mysql](https://www.google.ie/search?q=database%20diff%20programmes&oq=database%20diff%20programmes&aqs=chrome..69i57.4657j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=database%20diff%20programmes%20mysql)".

I also found this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31566/34007) helpful in realising that the information_schema tables are dynamic.

Maybe I'm a bit OCD too (can't let this go! :-) ) but I also found [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9569/fastest-way-to-check-if-innodb-table-has-changed) - check out the answer by Jacket - Percona may be the way to go if you are in real need of this functionality. However, it's obviously too late for your particular situation. I think it's backups for you :-(.